HTML Layout Mobile - LWC
Mobile version:

Desktop version:

<template>
<div style="min-height: 100vh; background-color: #FFFFFF; border-radius: 0px; box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
    <div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: space-evenly; align-items: center; padding: 1rem;">
        <div style="display: flex; align-items: center; background-color: #e0e0e0; padding: 0.5rem 1rem; border-radius: 8px;">
            <span style="font-size: 11px; color: #555;">Total Hours:</span>
            <span style={totalHoursStyle}>{totalHours}</span>
        </div>
        <div style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; max-width: 100%;">
            <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:chevronleft" alternative-text="Previous Date" size="small" variant="bare" onclick={handlePreviousDate} style="margin: 0;"></lightning-button-icon>
            <lightning-input class="custom-input" type="date" value={selectedDate} onchange={handleDateChange} 
                            style="margin: 0 0.25rem; width: 80vw; max-width: 100px; margin-bottom: 1rem; font-size: 10px;">
            </lightning-input>
            <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:chevronright" alternative-text="Next Date" size="small" variant="bare" onclick={handleNextDate} style="margin: 0;"></lightning-button-icon>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="height: 1px; background-color: #e0e0e0; margin: 0;"></div>

how do i align this on LWC for mobile. its displaying well on desktop version but its wonky on mobile version. it also looks different on IOS and Android.
<targets>
    <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
    <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
</targets>
<targetConfigs>
    <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
        <supportedFormFactors>
            <supportedFormFactor type="Small" /> 
            <supportedFormFactor type="Large" /> 
        </supportedFormFactors>
    </targetConfig>
    <targetConfig targets="lightning__AppPage">
        <supportedFormFactors>
            <supportedFormFactor type="Small" /> 
            <supportedFormFactor type="Large" /> 
        </supportedFormFactors>
    </targetConfig>
</targetConfigs>

